# LXD: Imported container doesn't start - Problem with ACLs

Tags: samba, lxd, bind, acl

I am just trying to launch a container, which was created on an other machine. 
I've done this the following way:

```
$ lxc snapshot container_name snapshot_name
$ lxc publish container_name/snapshot_name --alias image_name
$ lxc image export image_name
```

Copied the image to the other host with scp, then:

```
$ lxc image import dd2fd708361...a125d0d5885.tar.gz --alias image_name

$ lxc launch image_name container_name
```

Unfortunately, launching the container fails with:

```
Failed to change ACLs on /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/$CONTAINERNAME/rootfs/var/lib/samba/sysvol
```

The container ran in privileged mode, it is running Samba and Bind.

Can somebody please assist?

Comment: Hi! You question is somewhat advanced. I suggest to ask at https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/ where you can get help directly from the LXD developers.

Comment: Thank you, I've done that :)

Comment: Weird one..  Its the kind of thing I would expect if you'd installed LXD ontop of a filesystem which didn't support ACL's like ZFS.